# How to read barcodes using Android Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to scan barcodes using Android Phonegap. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the PhoneGap barcode tutorial [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3). It will take you step by step to creating a sample app with [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) via the PhoneGap plugin from [purplecabbage](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner).

Answer (score 5):

- You would have to build a Phonegap plugin which implements [the zxing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).
- Or use [the pre existing BarcodeScanner plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner) which is MUCH easier.

Comment: but how to workss this one?????                   how to call that java classssss?????

Comment: Read the readme, it will explain how zxing is used with the plugin.