# I need a Barcode Scanner to include it in my phonegap project

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i'm looking for an existing project / API for an Barcode Scanner. I want to include the Barcode Scanner to my phonegap project, so i should work using JavaScript ... . Any suggestions??? It must be able scan a BarCode, no QR code!!!

Just found: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ (But it only scans QR-codes?!)

Thank you!

Comment: zxing scans more than just QR codes, it scans just about anything.

Comment: There are answers here on [phonegap barcode scanning for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840996) and [phonegap barcode scanning for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888396).

Comment: This is a duplicate of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311380/phonegap-barcode-scanner/8312730#8312730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these phonegap barcode scanner plugins for [Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner), [iPhone](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner) or [Blackberry](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/BarcodeScanner).

Good luck.