# How to get the bar code with just a photo of it? Using Android

Tags: android, cordova, barcode

I've been struggling to find a solution to this. The use case is - a person takes a photo of the barcode and my app will figure the bar code number.

I am currently using **PhoneGap** with HTML, CSS and Javascript on Android.

Can someone please tell me how do to do this? 
Even a link to a resource will be very helpful.

Comment: just use intent to scan that file

Comment: What is intent? How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried zxing? http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854442/embed-zxing-library-without-using-barcode-scanner-app

Comment: yes i tried but it seems so confusing so i need some tutorial that help me to implement it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840996/how-to-read-barcodes-using-android-phonegap..please see this question

Comment: Here is a very short tutorial how to scan barcodes with phonegap: https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-phonegap